# Mobile Cordova / phonegap facebook login without plugin, using only url

Tags: facebook, cordova

This login system is working perfectly on desktop clients. The user is redirect to facebook to allow the app and then redirected to my website:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&scope=" + scope;
```

However, in cordova/phonegap, that url is sent but this error is received in chrome:

`http://undefined/proxy/https://graph.facebook.comhttps://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1567960953444888&redirect_uri=this_is_correct%2Ffacebook_login.php&scope=user_friends&state=1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

My server login is made so that I just need to output "success login" to the user. So, even if the actual login wasn't working at least there should be output of this message. Any wonder on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be caused by two things.

Maybe the url can't be resolved due to whitelists. Use this plugin if you aren't using it, and use wildcards just for test

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

If not, are the desktop login using some kind of cookies? Maybe you have to use it.

Comment: nope, not using cookies and I am already allowing wildcard access. Should I try to reach this url via POST or GET? I want the url http request to be sent and server treated, but only that...

Comment: Hello del, could you please take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993033/send-request-to-page-in-javascript-phonegap-without-redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is malformed, but that seems so apparent I don't mean to insult anyone by stating it... see bold items below...

http://**undefined**/proxy/https://graph.facebook.com**MISSING_SLASH_HERE**https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1567960953444888&redirect_uri=this_is_correct%2Ffacebook_login.php&scope=user_friends&state=1