# Send request to page in javascript (phonegap) without redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, cordova

Basically I'm searching for a `href` without the redirect. I have the following function

```
if(custom_options !== undefined){
        op = custom_options;
        op.url = url;
        op.data = data;
        op.type = type;
    }else{
        op = {
            type: type,
            data: data,
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            async: true
        }; 
    }

    $.ajax(op);
```

Which sends an ajax request to specified url but it is always failing with `undefined/proxy/...` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865872/mobile-cordova-phonegap-facebook-login-without-plugin-using-only-url) to various urls, so I am believing the problem is within the function. How can I execute the url without redirection and handle the feedback?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no... I'm programming the app in the computer and testing it in the browser... So, the request comes from the browser...